# Java group tile matrix by largest possible AABB

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, aabb

i'm making a 2D tile based game and i was working with AABB collision algorithm
when i got stucked in this problem, i have a matrix of tile:

```
Tile[][] matrix = new Tile[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

interface Tile {
    public boolean isSolid();
}
```

based on this matrix i want calculate the AABB pool
that is a simple list, defined here:

```
List<AABB> aabbPool = new ArrayList<AABB>();

class AABB {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int w;
    private int h;

    // Getter and Setter // 

}
```

i'm looking for an algorithm that is capable of iterate the tile matrix
and find the largest possible AABB-Rectangle of solid attached tiles in the matrix,
let me explain:

[image: Tile representation]

```
Grid = The matrix
White = Unsolid tile
Black = Solid Tile
```

Given this matrix the algorithm will create the aabb pool, like this
[image: Tile result]

```
Red outline = Y preferred aabb
Green outline = X preferred aabb (Y is not possible)
Blue outline = XY group
```

At the end, i created this script for debug the algorithm

```
public class AABBDebugger {

    // Public field just for debug
    static class AABB {

        public int xPosition;
        public int yPosition;
        public int width;
        public int height;

    }

    // Public field just for debug
    static class Tile {

        public static final int SIZE = 10;

        public boolean solid;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Matrix size
        int WIDTH = 50;
        int HEIGHT = 50;

        // Declaration of matrix and random initialization
        Tile[][] matrix = new Tile[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
        for (int xCoord = 0; xCoord < WIDTH; xCoord++) {
            for (int yCoord = 0; yCoord < HEIGHT; yCoord++) {
                matrix[xCoord][yCoord] = new Tile();
                matrix[xCoord][yCoord].solid = Math.random() > 0.5;
            }
        }

        // Inizialization of the collission pool
        List<AABB> aabbPool = new ArrayList<AABB>();

        // Magic method that create the collision pool
        magicMethod(matrix, WIDTH, HEIGHT, aabbPool);


        // Rendering of result
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * Tile.SIZE, HEIGHT * Tile.SIZE));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;
            while ((bufferStrategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy()) == null) {
                canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
            }
            Graphics graphics = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();

            for (int xCoord = 0; xCoord < WIDTH; xCoord++) {
                for (int yCoord = 0; yCoord < HEIGHT; yCoord++) {
                    graphics.setColor(matrix[xCoord][yCoord].solid ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
                    graphics.fillRect(xCoord * Tile.SIZE, yCoord * Tile.SIZE, Tile.SIZE, Tile.SIZE);
                }
            }

            for (AABB aabb : aabbPool) {
                graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
                graphics.drawRect(aabb.xPosition, aabb.yPosition, aabb.width, aabb.height);
            }

            bufferStrategy.show();
            graphics.dispose();
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }


    /*
     * The algorithm that i'm looking for
     * for cycle start from Y rather then X
     */
    private static void magicMethod(Tile[][] matrix, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT, List<AABB> aabbPool) {
        for (int yCoord = 0; yCoord < HEIGHT; yCoord++) {
            AABB aabb = null;
            for (int xCoord = 0; xCoord < WIDTH; xCoord++) {
                if (matrix[xCoord][yCoord].solid) {
                    if (aabb == null) {
                        aabb = new AABB();
                        aabb.yPosition = yCoord * Tile.SIZE;
                        aabb.xPosition = xCoord * Tile.SIZE;
                        aabb.height = Tile.SIZE;
                        aabb.width = Tile.SIZE;
                    } else {
                        aabb.width += Tile.SIZE;
                    }
                } else if (aabb != null) {
                    aabbPool.add(aabb);
                    aabb = null;
                }
            }
            if (aabb != null) {
                aabbPool.add(aabb);
                aabb = null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The script produce this result:

[image: Script Result]

but isn't what i expect because this algorithm group the tiles
by y and is ok, but not by x when i can, like there

[image: Script Result Expected]

Finally (sorry for the long post) the algorithm must respect this rules:

- Prefer group the tiles by Y
- Group the tiles by X when is not possible by Y
- Don't overlap existing group
- Group all the tiles

Comment: What do you mean prefer by Y? I guess you mean at least consisting of two-boxes? because if a single-box is accepted, then your output descretization follows the rules.

Comment: You guessed right, i mean two or more attached tile by Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use your method with a slight change: Do not directly store single-tile AABB rectangles grouped by Y (those with `width==Tile.SIZE`); but store them in a temp HashMap: `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`, where the key is the `xCoord` of each tile and the value yCoord is added to the list). This way you can track which tiles per xCoord have not been grouped already by Y. So, check if `width!=Tile.SIZE` before adding:

```
if (aabb.width != Tile.SIZE) {
    aabbPool.add(aabb);
} else {
    addToMap(xCoord,yCoord);
}
aabb = null;
```

The method addToMap can be implemented as follows:

```
private static void addToMap(Integer x, Integer y, Map<Integer, List<Integer>> xMap) {
        if (xMap.containsKey(x)) {
            xMap.get(x).add(y);
        } else {
            List<Integer> yList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            yList.add(y);
            xMap.put(x, yList);
        }
    }
```

Then, call the following method as a last step of your `magicMethod`; it will either add single-tile AABB rectangles (not possible to be grouped anyway), or grouped by X (that are not grouped by Y already).

```
private static void groupByX(Map<Integer, List<Integer>> xMap, List<AABB> aabbPool) {
    //for each X
    for (Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : xMap.entrySet()) {
        List<Integer> curList = entry.getValue();
        if (curList != null) {
            int curY = curList.get(0); //current yCoord
            int curH = 1; //current height
            //for each Y
            for (int i = 1; i < curList.size(); i++) {
                if (curY + curH == curList.get(i)) {
                    curH++;
                } else {
                    aabbPool.add(new AABB(entry.getKey()*Tile.SIZE, curY*Tile.SIZE, Tile.SIZE, curH*Tile.SIZE)); // *Tile.SIZE()
                    //reset
                    curY = curList.get(i);
                    curH = 1;
                }
            }
            //add the last AABB
            aabbPool.add(new AABB(entry.getKey()*Tile.SIZE, curY*Tile.SIZE, Tile.SIZE, curH*Tile.SIZE));
        }
    }
}
```

This is what you get:

[image]

Comment: Can you implement this code in my AABBDebugger class ?

Comment: It's pretty easy to directly add it to your code. Anyway, get it here: http://chalkias.net/algorithms/AABB/AABBDebugger.java